# how deselect radio-button in angular 6?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular6

I can't deselect when a radio-button selected. what should i do?!

```
<div>
    <label id="sim-type-label">type of sim</label>
    <mat-radio-group formControlName="simType"
                     aria-labelledby="sim-type-label">
    <mat-radio-button value="false">Type1</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button value="true">Type2</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
</div>
```

I have two radio-button. If i select a radio-button then can't deselect it and i want with a click select and click again deselect. but how?! In angular 6 that's not worked by default! please help. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. What about the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/radio/overview) page? There is also a StackBlitz example attached.

Comment: What you want is the feature of the CheckBox, but you can implement your desired feature with (click) event

Comment: @hadi how can i do my desired feature with (click) event?! give me solution :))

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012311/deselect-radio-button-angular-2) QA

Answer (score 0):

The functionality of radio button is to select at least one from the group and as per your requirement its the functionality of checkbox  to select and deselect .

Comment: I want that user be able to select one of  "type1" or "type2" or none of them. @Manpreet